# Duplicate symbol error with pointer to constant, but not with constant pointer in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
// header
const char* NAME1 = "C++";        // linker error
const char* const NAME2 = "C++";  // fine
```

If this header is included in multiple source files, the first declaration leads to a linker error

> ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64

Why is the 2nd declaration allowed? Address of NAME2 identifier was same in both source files where the header was included. So somehow making NAME2 a constant pointer also changes its linkage. How does that work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-volatile non-inline const-qualified variables that aren't declared `extern` and aren't previously declared to have external linkage, declared in namespace scope, have internal linkage (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Linkage).

`NAME1` points to `const char`, but is not `const` so it has external linkage. `NAME2` is `const` so it gets internal linkage